# the keyboard did not appear when i click the textfield in a cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am using a textfield in a static cell to get input from keyboard, but when I run the simulator the textfield did not show up. I clicked the cell, it still did not work, I've tried the way "iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard ->
Uncheck 'Connect Hardware Keyboard'. The problem still exist,  I don't know whether I missed something, Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Hit ⌘+K to toggle the keyboard in the simulator.

Comment: I cannot understand. You cannot see a text field, a keyboard or both? I make a project with a static cells from scratch and all works fine.

Comment: You might want to reboot the Simulator

Comment: @dan, I've also tried that "⌘+K to toggle the keyboard" before, it doesn

Answer (score 0):

Is your textfield user Interaction enabled ? 
You can check it in the fourth tab of the right panel; In the "View section".